# phpVirtualBox - Control Remote Servers - Central Management

Tags: virtualbox, php, remote-management

Not sure if this is possible, all my google results come up with RDP stuff, or just basic, how to install phpVirtualBox.

I was wondering If I can **set up a Central phpVirtualBox and connect it to multiple VirtualBox servers?**

This way I can have centralized management of all my VM's from the same GUI.

**Update :**

It is possible!

[PHPVirtualBox with Mulitple Servers](https://sourceforge.net/p/phpvirtualbox/wiki/Multiple%20Server%20Configuration/)

But I am still struggeling with the concept in simple ways.

Lets say you have a Server and a PHPHost.

Does apache need to be on the Server?

Does PHPVirtualBox need to be on the Server?

Does VirtualBox need to be on the PHPHost?

Ideally, id like to not have PHPVirtualBox on the server and just run

**On Server :**

```
configure >> /etc/default/virtualbox
/etc/init.d/vboxweb-service start
```

**On PHPHost :**

Install PHPVirtualBox + Apache

Configure /var/www/html/phpvirtualbox/config.php

Am I getting this wrong, or does VBox + PHPVirtualBox combo need to be on all servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. According to their [sourceforge summary](https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpvirtualbox/) :

> As a modern web interface, it allows you to access and control remote VirtualBox instances.

You will need :

- one server with Apache/PHP for running phpVirtualBox,
- one or multiple server running as host with VirtualBox web services each of these host supporting one or multiple guests.

**But** as communication between them is based on an unencrypted SOAP protocol it's recommended to install all components on the same machine.

For more information read:

- [Manage VirtualBox over Web Interface](http://www.firstdigest.com/2010/08/manage-virtualbox-over-web-interface/) from the FirstDigest Technology Blog,
- [phpVirtualBox](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PhpVirtualBox) from the ArchLinux wiki

From `config.php-example`

```
// Multiple servers example config. Uncomment (remove /* and */) to use.
// Add ALL the servers you want to use. Even if you have the server set
// above. The default server will be the first one in the list.
/*
var $servers = array(
        array(
                'name' => 'London',
                'username' => 'user',
                'password' => 'pass',
                'location' => 'http://192.168.1.1:18083/',
                'authMaster' => true // Use this server for authentication
        ),
        array(
                'name' => 'New York',
                'username' => 'user2',
                'password' => 'pass2',
                'location' => 'http://192.168.1.2:18083/'
        ),
);
*/
```

Comment: Any experience with this? I'll have to check the configs see if I can see a IP port field but Im not so sure it doesn't have to be on the headless erver itself

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Wicked! Thanks I'm going to test then accept! This will be much better then phpvirtualbox on each server. My team will be very happy

Comment: Having some issues with the concept, but its definitely possible!

https://sourceforge.net/p/phpvirtualbox/wiki/Multiple%20Server%20Configuration/

Not sure if I should have started a new question, but I updated my question with some conceptual things I don't get still.

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: What about [libvirt](https://libvirt.org/index.html)? Has the advantages of offering built-in secured communication links, also supports many virtualization systems, in case you need to migrate...

Comment: Yes, but phpVirtualBox provides a web application allowing you to manage multiple remote VM's.